# Formatting Google Search Result

Tags: seo, google

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)

Hello,

I am new to search engine optimization. I am working on customizing how my results appear in Google as best as possible. I have learned about the meta tags to customize the text summary. However, I have some hierarchical parts to my website.

When a result appears related to the "tip-of-the-iceberg", I would like to show links related to the "child" pages. For instance, if you Google "Walmart" you will see the following links listed with the result:

- Electronics
- TV & Video
- Departments
- Furniture
- Toys
- Girls
- Living Room
- Computers

Is there any way that I can help Google determine which links to show and the text to display for these child links on my site? Or is this something that Google automatically generates?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean this?

[image]

You don't control whether or not Google shows this mini navigation menu for your site. Google decides to show it if your site is deemed popular and authoritative enough.

In practice, unless you're a major brand, it's not going to show up.

You might also want to look at 
[How do I get Google to show links to my site hierarchy in search results?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/443/)