# Google search results

Tags: google-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get Google to show links to my site hierarchy in search results?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/443/how-do-i-get-google-to-show-links-to-my-site-hierarchy-in-search-results)

In some search results I see something like categories below the results.

But I have no idea at all what is this and how can I do it for my page.

Sorry for this question and thank you in advance

[image]

Answer (score 2):

These are breadcrumbs on the websites wrapped in html that Google recognizes called rich snippets.

Read more about them here

Rich snippets - Breadcrumbs
http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185417