# How do websites get extra information in Google results?

Tags: seo, google

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get Google to show links to my site hierarchy in search results?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/443/how-do-i-get-google-to-show-links-to-my-site-hierarchy-in-search-results)

On Stack Overflow and many other websites, I've noticed there is some extra information under the result link. For example:

[image: Google SO result]

The *"6 answers - Jul 31, 2011"* part is what I'm talking about.

Does Google automatically do this or does the website have to do something to make Google add this extra information in search results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because several websites use [microformats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microformat) and [microdata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microdata_%28HTML5%29). Google (and other Search Engines) which recognize those formats can use them to add extra informations.